# Javascript jQuery then in interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm checking the server if a job is done. I don't want to spam the server so that's why I will use setInterval.

I call the trigger function, and when the job is done on the server (perhaps 2-3 calls before it's done), the function is done.

I know that I could call my finishFunction in the interval and kind of solve it. But I would like to return it because I call the trigger function from another js file. And if it's possible, I would like to handle it there.

```
function trigger() {
    var response = startInterval();
    response.then(function() {
        //done finishFunction()
    });
}

function checkServer() {
    var obj = { test: true }
    var respons = $.ajax({
        url: "MyUrl",
        data: JSON.stringify({ obj: obj }),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false
    });
    return respons;
}

function startInterval() {
    var inProgress = false;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (!inProgress) {
            inProgress = true;
            var response = checkServer().then(function (data) {
                var isDoneInQueue = JSON.parse(data.d);
                if (isDoneInQueue) {
                    //finishFunction()???
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return response;
                };

                inProgress = false;
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having with the code?

Comment: My problem was when I called startInterval my return wasn't my response. And I knew that it was because the function went through before it got my response. And as I said that I could call a function in "isDoneInQueue". But the answear belowe solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a `Deferred` object from the function, and resolve it when the server job is done:

```
function startInterval() {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    var inProgress = false;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (!inProgress) {
            inProgress = true;
            checkServer().then(function (data) {
                var isDoneInQueue = JSON.parse(data.d);
                if (isDoneInQueue) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    result.resolve(data);
                };
                inProgress = false;
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
    return result;
}
```

Whatever you call the `resolve` method with, is sent to the function that you use with the `then` method:

```
function trigger() {
    startInterval().then(function(data) {
        //done finishFunction()
    });
}
```